# Cannot import .csv file with unicode characters to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, unicode

I have a .csv file which has Unicode characters when I want to import it to Excel, it shows some garbage instead of the Unicode characters.

I googled and found some tips but did not work for me.

I try to import the file as follows:

1. First, it does not show UTF-8 option in file origin:
   [image: no utf-8 here]
2. I can see the right preview of the data here:
   [image: right preview]
3. When the file is imported I cannot see the right data. Excel shows garbage data instead.

Comment: Which version of Excel? Could it be that not all needed modules are installed? If I check this with Excel 2016, I see ~100 possible encodings in that dropdown, including _Unicode (UTF-8)_.

Comment: I have installed Ms. Office 2013 with typical installation.

Comment: No idea what's included in a 'typical' install, you may want to re-reun the installer and check if there's an optional module for this. But maybe utf-8 support was added after 2013.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256/3439404)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Excel.

A known reported workaround is to close Excel, then open a command prompt as Administrator (Windows search -> 'cmd' -> Right mouse click on Command Prompt -> 'Run as Administrator') and run the command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Then open Excel again, and check if all encodings are listed now.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a bit late, I will share my findings for future headaches.

I had a similar problem and the solution was on the system locale...

[image]

I disabled this beta feature and everything was fine.

Good Luck!!!

J!